# swfupload + classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, swfupload

i'm trying to run swfupload on classic asp, unfortunately i'm missing infos on how to process the upload in asp + aspupload - i'm looking for some sample scripts. any ideas?

thanks

Comment: could you give more details, and scripts to show what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

i have one, im using it in my app. i prepared the arhive to you:
http://ref.abau.org.ua/unloads.rar

get it please, i think you will find all info

Answer (score 0):

You can use plupload. That is a useful script.

First you should create upload page with asp.
Then using plupload script post data to asp page.

PLUpload Link: http://www.plupload.com/examples/

ASPUpload component example codes; http://www.aspupload.com/livedemo.html